# Python MysqlDb-How to store results of fetchone() in a list?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I need to store the result of fetchone() as separate elements in a list in python. To be in detail, soppose if fetchone() retrieves ***('1L','chuvi','21L','student')***, how can i store the retrieved result in a list in the following format ***self.res=[1L,'chuvi',21,'student']***.
I tried the following code:

```
self.res=[]  
self.res.append(con.fetchone())  
print self.res
```

but the output i got is : ***[(1L, 'chuvi', 21L,'student')]***. How can i store it as separate elements in the list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the extend method of list:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> res = []
>>> res.extend(a)
>>> res
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Hope it will help you .

Comment: it works in a normal case. But when i tried with fetchone() the list contains the whole tuple as the first element. but i need the tuple contents to split and get stored as separate elements of the list

Answer (score 0):

The result of `fetchone` is a tuple.  If you append it to your list, you get a list with a tuple in it.  If you want to make a list with the same *contents*, just do `self.res = list(con.fetchone())`.  In many cases, though, you don't need to do this; you can just use the tuple directly.

Comment: But Bren i still get the same output [(1L, 'chuvi', 21L,'student')]. i need to store the tuple as separate contents in a list like [1L,'chuvi',21,'student'] . how do i do that?

Comment: Are you saying that when you do `self.res = list(con.fetchone())` then it doesn't contain what you want?  I find it hard to believe.  Can you post the code and output when you try it that way?

Comment: The whole tuple is stored as the first element of the list.But all i want is i need to store tuple's elements as separate elements inside the list.

Comment: All i need is the tuple's contents should get split and should be stored as separate elements inside the list.